# Would recommendation letters from the chemists in the industry lab I work in be helpful?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter

A little background info,

I'm currently working as a lab technician in a drug lab which focuses on clinical chemistry and toxicology. I wish to eventually, within a few years tops, go back for my upper level degrees. I didn't have any close relationships with professors of mine as an undergrad, and as a result, I'm currently lacking possible grad school recommendations.

Would anyone recommend using recommendations from chemists, with PhD's, who work in the industry as beneficial grad school recommendations? They both serve as my employers/ bosses, and I'm 99.99% they would give high recommendations if asked. However, would these even help me on my applications?

Also, if anyone has any possible actions I could take that would help me strengthen a grad school application, that are possible with the time window mentioned above, 2-3 years, that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're applying for Ph.D. programs, the basic question admission committees usually need to answer is "Is X capable of becoming a good researcher?" If your supervisors, both of whom have Ph.D.'s, can answer that question successfully, then there's no reason not to use them—particularly if they know your work more closely than someone who only taught you in courses.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to aeismail's good answer, I would add, **don't worry.**

- Going back to graduate school after a few years in industry is normal.
- Not having close academic contacts for references in such a situation is normal, too.
- Being successful in industry lab work in your field is good, relevant experience.  In some ways, it puts you ahead of someone with a purely academic background who may have never held a "real" job.  Being able to just bear down and get the work done is a big part of success in any research degree.

> any possible actions I could take that would help me strengthen a grad
>   school application

If there were any way you could get involved in more research now, that would be a plus.  A couple of examples:

- Is your employer partnering with any academic researchers on projects?  If so, can you get involved somehow?
- Are you involved in any work that will be written up as peer-reviewed publications (or could be)?  Can you participate in this?

If you have a good relationship with one or both of your bosses, I would talk to them about your interest in being involved in more academic research, and see if there are any such opportunities.

Also, it's typically worth exploring whether your employer will support you getting a higher degree.  Sometimes they may pay for it, in return for you working for them for a few years.